# Dates of birth and death of Haim Hanani

Tags: math-history

I am currently studying the incredible 1960 paper ["On quadruple systems"](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v12/cjm1960v12.0145-0157.pdf) by Haim Hanani, and stumbled upon his [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim_Hanani) which states that Hanani died in April of 1991, but not on which day.

Then I did some researching and found an image of a [gravesite](https://billiongraves.com/grave/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%A0%D7%99/21870888) that I suspect is his. If it is, then his death date would be 23rd of Nisan, 5751 (Hebrew date) = April 7, 1991 (Gregorian date). The only thing that looks strange to me is that on the grave, the birth date is given as 22nd of Elul, 5672 = September 4, 1912, which contradicts the birth date of September 11, 1912 given in the Wikipedia entry.

Doe anyone here have access to additional resources that give the exact dates of birth and death? Is the WP article wrong about the birth date? Or was there more than one person named Haim Hanani? Professor Hanani surely deserves a "proper" WP entry.

Comment: According to a note in Wiadomości Matematyczne (in Polish) from 2000 the birth date is September 11, but the death date is not given https://wydawnictwa.ptm.org.pl/index.php/wiadomosci-matematyczne/article/view/4852/4425

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek: Thank you for the link. However, since it was written by R. Duda in 2000, it might simply have been copied from (or share the same source as) the 1995 [AMS death notice](http://www.ams.org/notices/199506/people.pdf) refered to by the WP article.